# What is it called? is it a rule?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

I have a high school friend. Yesterday her dad told her to not talk to me. Today she is talking to me. If I want to tell her that she is going against what her father said, what is it called? Is she going against the "rule"? I thought of "rule" but that doesn't seem right because it was not a rule but her father simply told her to not talk to me. What would you say she is going against what?

Comment: It ***is*** right, because she's ***breaking her father's rule***. Or ***going against*** his instructions / orders, if you like that better.

Comment: "You're going against your father's wishes."

Answer (score 2):

You would say to her, "You are disobeying your father."
She is being disobedient.

Comment: It is not very clear what your question is. Could you be more specific?

Comment: What you say is true but the OP wanted specifically some equivalent of the word _rule_ although in fact that is the correct word.